# Using an AdControl when Ads are unavailable, in TestMode, and the limits of keywords

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

When using the AdControl:

- Is it possible to have a background image display when the phone does not have connectivity to the Ad Server?   Maybe set the background to an `ImageBrush`?
- In the documentation it says there is an `AdControl.TestMode` property but I haven't found it (I'm using version 2.1.11120.1).
- Is there a limit or a recommendation for the max number of keywords for the AdControl.AdSelectionKeyWords proprety ?   I saw in the documentation that the limit for a *single* keyword is 255 chars, but it doesn't say anything about the length of the *entire* keywords string.

Comment: Whoa, that's three questions in one. :) Might want to break that out.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should break it out still, since Chris did some work for me to make it pretty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AdControl.TestMode` is a static property that you can probably set from anywhere in your app, at least in theory. You don't need a reference to the control.

In practice, you need to set `AdControl.TestMode` early in your application's lifecycle. I usually do it in the application's contstructor:

```
public App()
{
    ...
    InitializeComponent();

    AdControl.TestMode = false;

    ...
}
```

I have a [blog post](http://joshearl.wordpress.com/2011/04/17/using-display-ads-in-windows-phone-7-apps/) detailing how to do this.

I'm not sure about setting a background image. The behavior I've seen is that the control will load briefly, showing the border, then disappear. It seems like it might be collapsing, but it's hard to tell at runtime.

EDIT: OK, I did some playing around with a sample project and confirmed that the `AdControl` collapses when the ads are unavailable. I tried setting a background image in code but it wasn't displayed, since the control disappears if it doesn't have any ads to display.

If you want to avoid having a big hole in your application, a simple solution would be to put an `Image` control behind your `AdControl`. When the `AdControl` collapses, it will reveal the `Image`. Not as elegant as what you were hoping for, but it would work.

EDIT 2: Found the answer on the keywords question. The AppHub [submission guidelines](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/home/about/app_submission_walkthrough_description) state:

> Keywords - Keywords that can be used to assist users in finding your application in the Windows Phone Marketplace. A maximum of five keywords can be used, separated by commas.

So that's five terms, comma delimited, up to 255 characters.

EDIT 3: Found a [post](https://community.microsoftadvertising.com/forums/p/67646/94000.aspx) dating back to January of 2011 that indicates that pubCenter is ignoring the keywords property on the `AdControl`. And [this one](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/70516.aspx) indicating that it didn't seem to work as of February. I'm guessing they still don't work. If you're looking to target ads more appropriately to your audience, make sure your ad channel selections in pubCenter are relevant. You can also build a form into your app to allow your users to give you some demographic data. I'm planning to incorporate this into my apps at some point, and in exchange I'll unlock an extra feature or two. Win win. :)

Comment: I guess upvoting the answer is the best we can do. :)

Comment: I'll give that a try, Thanks.   Is there a way to test that on the emulator, or do I have to deploy to the phone and turn off all connectivity?

Comment: What I did to test was put the `AdControl` into release mode as described in my blog post, then add a couple of extra numbers to one of the required ad IDs. It doesn't link up properly with the ad server, so no ads. :) You could also just shut off your Internet connection while testing in the emulator (easier if you're using a laptop like me).

Comment: Sorry, I should of of been more specific, I wanted to know the limit for "AddSelectionKeywords" property.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ff973773(v=MSADS.10).aspx   MS says each keyword can be 255 chars but I dont see a limit on how many words.